# Decrementing month from january to december last year in java

Tags: java, datetime

I'm have a problem going from January back to December I tried various things but I'm getting the nullexception. I'm using a button and put a mouselistener so every time I click it, it decrements by a month. But after January, it won't decrement to December even if I change the year before check the month.

Here's what I did:

```
    Button btnNewButton = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
            moveCalendar("down");
        }
    });
```

then here's my moveCalendar..

```
public void moveCalendar(String move)
{
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    resetBox();
    if(move.equals("down") )
    {
        dummyMonth--;
        if(dummyMonth < 0)
        {
            dummyMonth = 11;
            dummyYear--;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dummyMonth++;
        if(dummyMonth > 11)
        {
            dummyMonth = 0;
            dummyYear++;
        }
    }

    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,dummyYear);
    setYear(dummyYear);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,dummyMonth);
    setMonth(dummyMonth);
    int dy = getFirstDay(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    int daysMonth = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    populateCalendar(dy-1,daysMonth,cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),dummyMonth);
}
```

I get nullexception.. any suggestion what's happening?

Comment: What line does the `NullPointerException` say it came from?  That will go a long way towards figuring out what's `null` here.

Comment: The exception comes with a type, a message, and a stack trace telling what happened and where, precisely. Don't ignore this incredibly useful information.

Comment: Would be useful if you post the stack trace of the npe too

Comment: First i cant see `dummyMonth` declare, second please put the trace log

Comment: Also, why aren't you just using `Calendar.roll()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Calendar.add() method, for example:

```
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/calendar_add.htm

Comment: `roll()` is probably a better option here, but the OP definitely shouldn't be doing this by hand.

Comment: indeed! This is exactly why these methods are provided, so that such tedious work and errors can be avoided! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

It has much better support for date and time manipulation than the stock java classes — so much so that it's the basis for the new standard [dates and times API](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) introduced in [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8). If you're using Java 8 or higher, use the java.time api instead.

In Joda-Time, you can easily move to the previous month with code like this:

```
YearMonth date = new YearMonth("2014-01");
date = date.minusMonths(1); //will equal 2013-11
```

Your question doesn't say whether you're just dealing with years and months, or with an exact date (year, month, and day) but either way you would use a [`minusMonths`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusMonths%28int%29) method, just with a different class (for an exact date use the [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class, for example).

To integrate with the UI controls properly, you would populate the controls after you've finished manipulating the date object by setting each control to the correct value from the date object.

This approach will be *much* easier than dealing with [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).

Comment: FYI: The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). Its creator, [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen), went on to lead [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) defining the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8+. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 20 ) 
.minusMonths( 1 )
```

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible `Calendar` & `Date` classes.

For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 20 ) ;
```

To do date-math, call the `plus…` & `minus…` methods.

```
LocalDate monthAgo = localDate.minusMonths( 1 ) ;  // Get same day-of-month in the previous month.
```

Or use a `Period` to represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline.

```
Period p = Period.ofMonths( 1 ) ;

LocalDate earlier = localDate.minus( p ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Used Java 8 Date and time API as follows :

```
    LocalDateTime dt2= LocalDateTime.of(2019,10,20, 12,45);
    System.out.println(dt2); //2019-10-20T12:45

    System.out.println(dt2.minusMonths(11));//2018-11-20T12:45
```